# How to save POSIXct data which includes date, time and time zone to a csv file?

Tags: csv, posixct

I have some POSIXct data which includes date, time and time zone,
    "2018-05-28 19:14:48 GMT" 
    "2018-05-28 19:16:28 GMT"
How can I write them to a csv file?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe write.table and write.csv essentially use `as.character` to coerce POSIXct objects to character on write. To export strings of timestamps in some other format, use `format` to convert data from POSIXct to character, then write to csv.

See `?format.POSIXct` for arguments that control output format. In this case, `usetz = TRUE` will include timezone abbreviation.

E.g.,

```
dt1 <- Sys.time()

dt1x <- format(dt1, use_tz = TRUE)

write.csv(dt1x, "dt1x.csv")
```